# How to move an image over the path between two location on map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project in which I am showing two random location and the path between them.I have used [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/) tutorial to accomplish.

Now i want to show the moving image from one location to another.I have already put markers on that two locations.and also I have saved the position in an arraylist.

I had found some similar posts but couldn't solve my issue.

Here is my code for moving the drawable:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                // System.out.println("Marker size:- " + MarkerPoints.size());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_16);

                        while (i < MarkerPoints.size()) {
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(MarkerPoints.get(i))
                                    .title("Current Location")
                                    icon(icon);

                            System.out.println(MarkerPoints.get(i));
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            i++;
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        }
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to accomplish this.May be this is not the best way but it solves the problem.I am posting this so in future if someone needs to do stuff like that,It can be helpful.

I have store all the points in an ArrayList called `MarkerPoints` that we get from the API and use it to draw the image on ever point.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Runnable
{
private Thread thread = null;
volatile boolean isRunning;
private ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints; //This arrayList contains all points that are on the route
int i = 0;
Marker marker;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_trip_maps);

        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (isRunning) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    update();
                }
            });

            control();

        }
    }

    public void update() {

        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_16);
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MarkerPoints.get(i))
                .title("Current Location")
                .icon(icon));

        System.out.println(MarkerPoints.get(i));
        i++;
        if (i > MarkerPoints.size() - 1) {
            isRunning = false;

        }
    }

    public void control() {
        try {
            thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This will give the moving effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private double bearingBetweenLocations(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {
    final double PI = 3.14159;
    final double lat1 = latLng1.latitude * PI / 180;
    final double long1 = latLng1.longitude * PI / 180;
    final double lat2 = latLng2.latitude * PI / 180;
    final double long2 = latLng2.longitude * PI / 180;

    final double dLon = (long2 - long1);

    final double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    final double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;

    return brng;
}
```

Comment: use this useful links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277437/i-want-to-move-icon-from-one-location-point-to-another-point-where-icon-should-m

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have current and destination co-ordinates like below.

```
private LatLng CURRENT_LOC = new LatLng(23.013171, 72.522300);
private LatLng DESTINATION_LOC = new LatLng(23.013481, 72.522496);
```

After that add marker on google map

```
if (googleMap != null)
{
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.truck_16);

    MarkerOptions current = new MarkerOptions().position(CURRENT_LOC).title("Current Point");
    current_marker = googleMap.addMarker(current);
    current_marker.setIcon(icon);
    current_marker.setFlat(true);

    MarkerOptions destination = new MarkerOptions().position(DESTINATION_LOC).title("Destination Point");
    destination_marker = googleMap.addMarker(destination);
    destination_marker.setFlat(true);
}
```

And move marker on click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_move:

        float rotate = (float) bearingBetweenLocations(CURRENT_LOC, DESTINATION_LOC);

        rotateMarker(rotate);

        break;
    }
}
```

below all are methods that move marker from current location to destnation

```
private double bearingBetweenLocations(LatLng latLng1,LatLng latLng2)
{
    double PI = 3.14159;
    double lat1 = latLng1.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long1 = latLng1.longitude * PI / 180;
    double lat2 = latLng2.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long2 = latLng2.longitude * PI / 180;

    double dLon = (long2 - long1);

    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;

    return brng;
}

public void rotateMarker(float rotate)
{
    if (current_marker != null)
    {
        //final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        //final LatLng startPosition = current_marker.getPosition();
        final float startRotation = current_marker.getRotation();
        final float angle = 180 - Math.abs(Math.abs(startRotation - rotate) - 180);
        final float right = WhichWayToTurn(startRotation, rotate);

        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (current_marker == null) // oops... destroying map during animation...
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    //newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, toLatLng(location));
                    float rotation = startRotation + right * v * angle;
                    current_marker.setRotation(rotation);
                    //current_marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                //current_marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                animateMarker(current_marker, DESTINATION_LOC, false);
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}

public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition, final boolean hideMarker)
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = googleMap.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 5000;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private float WhichWayToTurn(float currentDirection, float targetDirection)
{
    float diff = targetDirection - currentDirection;
    if (Math.abs(diff) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(diff > 180)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you.