# How to move marker like car goes on road in android map for current location in fragment class

Tags: android

In app i am getting current location in fragment class it does not change when moves to other location in android studio.

1. I want create app current moving like car in my googlemap(marker) in fragment.
2. What is method onLocationChanged?
3. What is Interpolator?

Comment: just use onLocationChange method and update marker position

Comment: use location changed listener -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41828471/3425390

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

Location location;
ImageView adddatanotfoundimage;
LinearLayout walletsnackbar;
Context mcontext;
TextView totbal;
List<String> noparkingarrayid;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

String lat1, lat2, long1, long2;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
Marker marker;
String address;
static String Location1 = "";
static String Location2 = "";

protected LatLng mCenterLocation = new LatLng(26.9598505, 75.77874);
final LatLng SomePos = new LatLng(12.7796354, 77.4159606);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mcontext = MainActivity.this;

    try {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       // mGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
       // mGoogleMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
       // mGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SomePos));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target)
                .zoom(17)
                .bearing(30)
                .tilt(45)
                .build()));

        marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(SomePos)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                .title("Hello world"));


        mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

                final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
                final LatLng finalPosition = new LatLng(12.7801569, 77.4148528);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
                final float durationInMs = 3000;
                final boolean hideMarker = false;
                bearingBetweenLocations(SomePos,finalPosition);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    long elapsed;
                    float t;
                    float v;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Calculate progress using interpolator
                        elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                        t = elapsed / durationInMs;

                        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(
                                startPosition.latitude * (1 - t) + finalPosition.latitude * t,
                                startPosition.longitude * (1 - t) + finalPosition.longitude * t);

                        marker.setPosition(currentPosition);

                        // Repeat till progress is complete.
                        if (t < 1) {
                            // Post again 16ms later.
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                        } else {
                            if (hideMarker) {
                                marker.setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                marker.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return true;

            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void requestLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {

            Log.e("LatitudeMap", "" +location.getLatitude());
            Log.e("LogtitudeMap",""+location.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

Comment: I am using Api 25 post cannot resloved symbol